# 403 Forbidden error for "Collect In Store Checkout Shipping Option"

Tags: extensions, collection, shopping

Request your help to sort following error.

I am trying hands on on “Collect In Store Checkout Shipping Option”.

While I am trying to install extension with steps mentioned ahead I get error mentioned below

REDIRECTED URL: 
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Pook_CollectInStore/

**ERROR:**

Forbidden 
You don’t have permission to access url on this server. 
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at connect20.magentocommerce.com Port 80

Steps:

1. Accessed following EXTENSION PAGE URL 
   http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/collect-in-store-checkout-shipping-option.html
2. Ticked check box : I agree to the extension license agreement.
3. Clicked button : Get Extension Key
4. This showed text box with URL
5. Clicked Select Key to select URL, copied it and pasted to new browser window. Hit Run / enter to browse URL
6. Page gave ERROR : 403 Forbidden 
   You don’t have permission to access url on this server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the way magento connect functions.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use this key within Magento Connect on your Magento installation. Ignore the 403 error for now.

```
- Sign into your Magento store admin panel.
- Navigate to System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager.
- Paste in the extension key and click “Install”. If you run into any issues, consult the extension’s documentation forum. (Accessible from the extension’s page on Magento Connect.)
```

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/what_is_a_magento_connect_extension_key

Answer (score 2):

You're supposed to paste the key into your Magento Connect Manager via Admin Panel:

There is a guide available for installation: [How to Install Magento Connect Extension](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/InstallingMagentoConnectExtensions4%200.pdf)

Follow steps 8-10:

8 Log in to your Magento Store Admin Panel

9 Navigate to System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager

10 Paste the extension key in Step 2 field and click Install.